# Best practice for dealing with long running JEditorPane setText process

Tags: java, settext, jeditorpane

All processors that update my swing GUI from places other than by user clicks are performed using EventQueue.invokeLater (for example output generated from a long running background non-EDT thread process).

In my current scenario I have a TCPIP socket read background thread process that returns data which needs to update a JEditorPane object. I use the JEditorPane setText call. The problem is, placing the setText call in an invokeLater routine freezes the GUI for large files (example case test 19,790 KB).

My attempt to resolve this is to perform the setText action in a non-EDT background thread. This appears to solve the problem, BUT, I am concerned about best practices, because JEditorPane setText in java 7 (the JDK I’m using) is NOT thread safe.

HOWEVER trawling through the JDK code, it seems to me that the lengthy process performed here is in JDKs DefaultEditorKit.read, and within that method the only code that would effect the GUI is in the doc.insertString calls (unless I am mistaken). Now when you look at JDKs PlainDocument.java insertString method it documents that IT IS thread safe, so one would think therefore that this solution is sound.

HOWEVER...

Stress testing my application, I do some random clicks around the GUI, and currently have a tree node animation running, and during the large load below, it does appear to slow down the animation a little, hence my concern that I’ve not performed the best resolution (also very concerned about future JREs screwing me up here and therefore not relying on insertString currently being threadsafe).

I’ve investigated and seen that this question “how to handle long running JEditorPane setText” has been asked before but with no suitable answers.

**QUESTION 1)** Does anyone have thoughts on my current observations?

**QUESTION 2)** Does anyone have ideas on how I could achieve this another?

NOTE JEditorPane is my only choice here because I will be eventually supporting dynamic fonts of an IDE look and feel nature.

NOTE also that the below call is called within a EventQueue.invokeLater routine, so the initial editorPane work is in the EDT.

```
public void updateBigDataEditorPane( final JEditorPane editorPane, final String inStr ) {
    // Update editor object and content.
    editorPane.setContentType( "text/plain" );
    editorPane.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Monospaced", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
    editorPane.setDocument( editorPane.getEditorKit().createDefaultDocument() );
    // Content update. NOTE in non-EDT thread to stop GUI freeze with large content.
    new Thread( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //// synchronized
            synchronized( tabsLock ) {
                // Set content.
                editorPane.setText( inStr );
            } //// synchronized
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Use a SwingWorker to download the text and use it's done method to apply it...

Comment: @MadProgrammer SwingWorker would be applying the same principle as above (and once I've established the correctness of above I'll change it to use SwingWorker). That is, the setText is done in the background and not in the EDT (thats essentially what SwingWorker is about, right?), then any post actions required on the EDT are done in the done method. I'm assuming that is what you mean, because otherwise putting the setText in the SwingWorker done method would have the same effect as my original problem code - performing setText in the EDT freezes the GUI. Thoughts?

Comment: No. SwingWoker provides you with publish/process methods which allows you to synchronise updates with the EDT. The fact is, you could simply use the done method, which is also called within the EDT to update the UI. Remember, Swing is, generally, not thread safe.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, but this approach will still cause the original GUI freeze problem. setText (with large data) on the EDT thread freezes the GUI. Unless of course I break up the large data into chunks as inspired by ben's solution, and synchronize these chunk GUI updates on the EDT using SwingWorker approach you suggest.

Comment: You could still use publish and process to send "chunks" to the EDT and process them while the doInBackground method is still running

Comment: Ya that's what I meant. Ok so if I dont get other ideas I'll try 'chunk' management via SwingWorker... the more I think about it, the more this seems the only real 'proper' approach.

Comment: The other problem is, if your seeding something like HTML, the editor may not be able to display it until the text is compete...

Comment: Yup, thats when the chunks would need to be 'chunked' intelligently. Which makes me think I wish I could build a editorpane behind the scenes and then set the active editorpane to the built one. Building this non-active editorpane object in the background doesnt affect the GUI at all, but my attempt at then setting (switching) the active editorpane to this, just didnt work... might re-visit this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the answers provided were beneficial, and would be used to address specific long running EDT thread requirements, the solution I ended up using was as follows;

1. Create a new JEditorPane object
2. Perform the time consuming setText call
3. On completion, replace currently active JEditorPane object on the GUI with this newly created one.

Use SwingWorker to perform the background non-EDT tasks (1 & 2), and then perform step 3 on completion on the EDT thread.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the EditorPane's Document (via editorPane.getDocument()) and perform the changes to this document (via insertString(...), instead of using setText(...)) in another thread.

By doing this, you can (kind of) dynamically (means: while reading) write the contents.

As Example (add text from file to Textpane, without freezing UI):
(**EDIT**: this new code is **not** tested, but it should better demonstrate my suggestion...):

```
public void readFileAsync()
{
    final String fileName = "/path/to/file.txt";
    final StyledDocument doc = yourTextPane.getStyledDocument();

    Runnable r = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try 
            {
               List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName), Charset.defaultCharset());
               for (String line : lines) 
               {
                  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                           doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), line, null );
                        }
                    });
               }
            } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: The thread sycnhronisation states have changed recently and this may not be thread safe...

Comment: @Ben performing changes on document: If done via EDT has the same GUI freeze problem as originally reported. If done out of EDT essentially becomes the same solution I originally proposed - the only difference being that my proposed solution performs the pre document insert actions (code in setText and read described above) outside of the EDT.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Right now in the JDK 7 version that I am using, the document insertString method is threadsafe, if indeed the solution above is sound, I'll then need to investigate the ramifications of delivering my JDK7 built code on later JREs (I wont ask that question here for fear of downvotes given that I havent looked into that yet).

Comment: @Frank: i edited my code example, to better make clear what i meant.

Comment: @Ben thanks Ben, ya ok I see where you're going with the dynamic 'feel'. For a file of this size, the line by line approach I imagine would add alot more processing time to an already pretty long scenario, but I get that this was just an example on your part, so for my solution I'll take your idea and perform the inserts a block of data at a time (actually pretty much just like JDKs DefaultEditorKit.read does) ... still I'd like to avoid having to omit/replicate what JEditorPane.setText and DefaultEditorKit.read are doing before doing doc.insert.

Comment: @Ben definitely a more than satisfactory solution if nothing else comes up. Thanks! (unfortunately I cannot upvote though).

Comment: Document might be thread safe, but the JEditorPane isn't (or more to the point, those elements listening to DocumentChange events aren't). There's a lot more to thread safety then just the method you are calling

Comment: And wouldn't line need to be final?

Comment: Ben advised this was untested, so I took it as pseudo code to illustrate his concept.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, regarding JEditorPane listening events not being threadsafe, ok good point.

Comment: @FrankF I've had similar problems byte me the rear, took weeks to track it down :P